# Google Maps API: Wait until Cloud-based styling applied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to wait until the Cloud-based styling of a Google Map has been applied before displaying it?

Currently my map appears with default styling, then after 1-2 seconds updates with my Cloud-based styling. Since my Cloud-based colours are quite different, this is jarring.

I tried waiting for the map `idle` event, but that fires before styling gets applied.

Comment: AFAIK there is no specific event listener for that but *just* applying a map style doesn't take that long on my side. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: That said, when using Data-driven styling **and** a cloud-based map style, I indeed see the default style for a short time, then the style + feature are displayed and apparently, as you already found out, the `idle` event fires before this happens. I have opened a new [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261461441) in the issue tracker. Wait and see.